# If $D_1,D_2 \in \mathbb R ^2, D_1 \cap D_2 \neq \emptyset $ are two open discs, then $\exists D_{(a,b)} \subset D_1 \cap D_2$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

In an exercise I have to prove the following:

> Let $D_1,D_2 \in \mathbb R ^2$ be two open discs with $D_1 \cap D_2 \neq \emptyset$. If $(a,b)$ is any point in $D_1 \cap D_2$, show that there exists an open disc $D_{(a,b)}$ with center $(a,b)$ such that $D_{(a,b)} \subset D_1 \cap D_2$.

---

**My approach:**

Let $\bar D_1$ and $\bar D_2$ be the closure of the respective sets. Let $\partial(D_1\cap D_2)$ be the border of the intersection of $\bar D_1$ with $\bar D_2$. If we denote the $A=(a,b)$ then we can define: $\epsilon = \min \{\ \overline{XA},\  \forall X \in \partial(D_1\cap D_2)\}$.

If we define $D_{(a,b)}$ to be the open ball with center $(a,b)$ and with radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, Then $D_{(a,b)} \subset D_1 \cap D_2$.

---

Is is this proof valid? If so,is this argument enough or do I need to prove or to add anything else? What other interesting ways there exists to prove this?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this approach, but you can substantially improve the rigor behind your proof if you replace $\min$ with $\inf$ as the $\min$ may not exist for some bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, e.g. $\left\{ 1/2^{n} \colon n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$. Also, you'll have to show that $\epsilon > 0$ from the definition of $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ as open sets. I mean, if $\epsilon = 0$, then we'll have problems defining $D_{\left(a, b\right)}$ as a disk, right? :)

Comment: Because $A \in D_1 \cap D_2$, and $ D_1 \cap D_2 = (\bar D_1 \cap \bar D_2) \setminus \partial(D_1\cap D_2)$, and $X \in \partial(D_1\cap D_2)$, then $\overline {AX}$ is never 0. Does this prove it? @RoycePacibe

Comment: You mean $A$ and $X$ lie on disjoint places so $A \neq X$ and that means we'll never have $\overline{AX} \neq 0$ which is indeed true. Now, the problem is that you can have a set of non-zero numbers whose $\inf$ is still $0$ (take my example with $1/2^n$) so this still does not guarantee yet that $\epsilon \neq 0$ even if all $\overline{AX}$'s are not zero. Maybe you'll need some fixed neighborhood of $A$ to do this? :)

Comment: But there is no need to use an $\inf$ instead of the $\min$ here I think. There is always at leas one point that's the closest to a point $A$, so there exists a minimum, right? In this case there will always exists two points. @RoycePacibe

Comment: Yes, it is true there is always a minimum. Then in that case, either you'll have to prove the trivial result that "there exists at least one point $X$ that is closest to point $A$", or just explicitly state that "clearly, there exists at least one point $X$ that is closest to point $A$, so $\epsilon$ has to exist as a non-zero real number" while relying on the intuition of your reader. Personally, I think that explicitly adding that statement is enough because that is already trivial. :)

Comment: Then, add that fact that $A$ and $X$ are never the same points because they are in disjoint places so $\overline{AX}$ is never zero, and hence $\epsilon$ is never zero, and you are done. :)

Comment: In this context it's the same to have a $\min$ or a $\inf$? @RoycePacibe

Comment: Yes, just explicitly add the statement that "clearly, there is at least one point $X$ that is closest to $A$ so the $\min$ must exist" and you can use $\min$ in the proof instead of $\inf$. In this way, you have also eliminated the doubt on the existence of $\min$ in this context. :)

Comment: Thank you @RoycePacibe :)

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of curiosity, here it is an alternative solution based on the concept of distance.

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space. Then any open ball is open as it has been proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746613/proving-that-d-x-y-in-mathbb-r-2-x2-y2-1-is-opened/3746636#3746636). Based on it, we can solve the exercise proposed.

Let us consider two open balls $B(x_{0},\delta)$ and $B(y_{0},\varepsilon)$ whose intersection $B(x_{0},\delta)\cap B(y_{0},\varepsilon)$ is not empty.

Let $y\in B(x_{0},\delta)\cap B(y_{0},\varepsilon)$. Then we conclude there exist $B(y,r_{1})\subseteq B(x_{0},\delta)$ and $B(y,r_{2})\subseteq B(y_{0},\varepsilon)$ for some positive real numbers $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $r_{1}\leq r_{2}$. Then $B(y,r_{1})\subseteq B(y,r_{2})\subseteq B(y_{0},\varepsilon)$.

Based on the previous arguments, we finally conclude that $B(y,r_{1})\subseteq B(x_{0},\delta)\cap B(y_{0},\varepsilon)$, and we are done.

Hopefully it is useful.